# How does one double link an image

Tags: javascript, carousel, href

I have a carousel: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv9oqmk8/12/). I am trying to figure out how to link each image that appears as the main image to its own page. At the moment, clicking on an image leads to the Wikipedia page as this is the link I specified in the `main_image` div.

Should I specify one more `href` in the `<li>`? My guess is that I have to create one more variable in the JS on the lines of `var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href")`, but I am not at all sure how exactly.

```js
var intervalId;
var slidetime = 2500;
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Comment out this line to disable auto-play
  intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);
  $(".main_image .desc").show(); // Show Banner
  $(".main_image .block").animate({
    opacity: 0.85
  }, 1); // Set Opacity
  $(".image_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active');


  $(".image_thumb ul li").click(function() {
    // Set Variables
    var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //  Get Alt Tag of Image
    var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); // Get Main Image URL
    var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html(); //  Get HTML of block
    var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height(); // Calculate height of block 

    if ($(this).is(".active")) { // If it's already active, then...
      return false; // Don't click through
    } else {
      // Animate the Teaser    
      $(".main_image .block").animate({
        opacity: 0,
        marginBottom: -imgDescHeight
      }, 250, function() {
        $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({
          opacity: 0.85,
          marginBottom: "0"
        }, 250);
        $(".main_image img").attr({
          src: imgTitle,
          alt: imgAlt
        });
      });
    }

    $(".image_thumb ul li").removeClass('active'); // Remove class of 'active' on all lists
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add class of 'active' on this list only
    return false;

  }).hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });

  // Function to autoplay cycling of images
  function cycleImage() {
    var onLastLi = $(".image_thumb ul li:last").hasClass("active");
    var currentImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active");


    if (onLastLi) {
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li:first");
    } else {
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active").next();
    }

    $(currentImage).removeClass("active");
    $(nextImage).addClass("active");

    // Duplicate code for animation
    var imgAlt = $(nextImage).find('img').attr("alt");
    var imgTitle = $(nextImage).find('a').attr("href");
    var imgDesc = $(nextImage).find('.block').html();
    var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();

    $(".main_image .block").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      marginBottom: -imgDescHeight
    }, 250, function() {
      $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({
        opacity: 0.85,
        marginBottom: "0"
      }, 250);
      $(".main_image img").attr({
        src: imgTitle,
        alt: imgAlt
      });
    });
  };

});
```

```css
.features {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*    width: 60%;  */
  min-width: 62.4%;
  max-width: 62.4%;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.main_image {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-width: 72.3%;
  max-width: 72.3%;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  /*       border-top: 5px solid blue; */
  /*       border-right: 5px solid red;
 */
}
.main_image img {
  margin-right: 0;
  max-height: 475px;
  padding-right: 0;
  max-width: 610px;
}
.main_image h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /*  font-variant: small-caps; */
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: italic;
}
.block small {
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background: url(images/icon_cal.gif) no-repeat 0 center;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.main_image .block small {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.main_image .desc {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.main_image .block {
  width: 100%;
  background: #111;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.image_thumb {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 223px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  /*       border-right: 1px solid #fff; */
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}
.image_thumb ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  /*       border: 4px solid green; 
 */
}
.image_thumb ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  min-width: 213px;
  height: 56.2px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image_thumb ul li.hover {
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_thumb ul li.active {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
.image_thumb ul li h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /*  font-variant: small-caps; */
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: italic;
}
.image_thumb ul li .block {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="features">

  <span class="sticker">
     <img class="tab1special" src="images/featurestab.png" alt="main">
       </span>

  <div class="main_image">
    <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Baker's-van-r.jpg" />
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <div class="block">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Wagon wins again</h2>
  </div>


  <div class="image_thumb">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Baker's-van-r.jpg"></a>
        <div class="block">
          <h2>Wagon wins again</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/00/60/ff/0060ff20d110050c0e350c55f7c7f3be.jpg"></a>
        <div class="block">
          <h2>Heirloom Scareloom</h2>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Mammuthus_trogontherii122DB.jpg"></a>
        <div class="block">
          <h2>The Original Wollies</h2>
          <br>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/booksleeve2.jpg"></a>
        <div class="block">
          <h2>Tales from the West</h2>
          <br>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/spiceroute.jpg"></a>
        <div class="block">
          <h2>A Journey through Time</h2>
          <br>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create two hyperlinks on the same element. How would the browser know which link to follow? Why not create a separate text element crediting the Wikipedia page, with that link, and use the image div as your page link?

Comment: but am not trying to link each image to 2 different pages. In the code, u'll see that the a href specified for image_thumb elements, is an image and not really a page to go to. This image appear in the main_image space during auto rotation. What i'm unable to do is have that image linked to a page of its own (wikipedia was just a test - and it applies to all pages; how would i apply a unique link to each image?).

Answer (score 0):

Images cannot be links. But you can **wrap images in links** very easily with jQuery. Your current code has:

```
$(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
```

which sets the source and the alternate text of the current image. If you want to wrap that image in a link, you can do:

```
$(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt}).wrap($('<a>',{
     href: imgTitle // over whatever URL you like
  }));
```

This wraps the img tag in a link. Currently it just links to the image source, but you can change it to anything.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to have **two** links from an image.